# Oracle - how to display data according to row contents using curly braces { }

Tags: sql, oracle

please help me, I'm having trouble solving this Query

I have data

```
|account_id|name_format                        |first_name|last_name|surname |
|1         |{first_name} {last_name} {surname} |John      |Doe      |john_doe|
|2         |{surname} {first_name} {last_name} |Jane      |Doe      |jane_doe|
|3         |{first_name} {last_name}           |Baby      |Doe      |baby_doe|
```

and then I will display the data like this

```
|account_id|name_format                        |display_name     |
|1         |{first_name} {last_name} {surname} |John Doe john_doe|
|2         |{surname} {first_name} {last_name} |jane_doe Jane Doe|
|3         |{first_name} {last_name}           |Baby Doe         |
```

What is the correct query to display the above data? i use oracle

Comment: try this "select account_id, name_format, replace(replace(replace(name_format,'{first_name}', first_name), '{last_name}', last_name), '{surname}', surname) as display_name from table_name". You can also write your own function that does this nicer and more programmable

Comment: @OracleDev, You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
select account_id, name_format, replace(replace(replace(name_format,'{first_name}', first_name), '{last_name}', last_name), '{surname}', surname) as display_name 
from table_name
```

You can also write your own function that does this nicer and more programmable.